# RabbitMQ Headers Exchange where X-Match equals any

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I have created a headers exchange and bound it to three queues with different arguments as following:

[image]

Then I try to publish a message where **any** queue with **format: pdf** would receive it, like this:

[image]

But the exchange seems to not be able to route it to the proper queues, as I get the following message:

[image]

Since I can't find people with the same problem as I have, it might be something I am doing wrong here

Note that, for instance, if I send **x-match:all**, **format: pdf** and **type: report**, the queue **test-queue-A** gets it normally

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be I'm misunderstanding the various pictures you provided in your description, but based on the info available [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers)

It seems like you're adding the `x-match=any` to the headers of your message,
while **it's expected in the binding between your exchange and your queue**.

It indicates how the binding works:

Either **any** common header between the message and the binding count as a **match**,

Or **all** the headers referenced in the binding need to be present in the message for it to **match**.

Comment: You're right! I was following this tutorial https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html that made me understand that the x-match went in the message's header, but the official document corroborates with what you said. Thanks!

Comment: That tutorial is certainly misleading, I came here after reading that tutorial as I was also confused where the x-match header is supposed to go.

Comment: Sorry that we confused thing, we will update the blog image right away!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Olivier for the link which you have shared, it helped to understand the header exchange much better. I know this question is asked 5 years ago and answered by @Olivier. But still, after 5 years there are not many resources to understand how to create the Header type exchange which is quite tricky when other types of exchanges(Direct & Topic) are a bit easy to create and bind the Queues as they use the routing key concept and the fanout doesn't need either routing key or headers.

To create a header type exchange please follow the steps, which I have followed

1. Log in to your rabbitMQ management UI.
2. Create some **Queues** first in the Queues tab.
3. Create an exchange in the **Exchanges** tab by giving some name in Name, choosing the **Type** as **headers** in the dropdown and clicking Add exchange.
4. Click on the created exchange from the list of exchanges.
5. click on the **Bindings** Accordion.
6. Enter the **Queue Name** in the text box next to the **To queue** dropdown.
7. In the **Arguments** fill the key **x-match** and value as **any/all**.
8. Add all the other arguments as per your requirements.
9. Click on Bind.
10. Do the same for the other queues which you want to bind to this exchange.

Finally, the bindings will look like this

[Binding a Queue as match all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN2qk.png)

[After binding the Queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0IKz.png)

Hope this will be helpful. Thank you. BTW this is my first post in Stack Overflow!